# How to sort by condition in entityQuery

Tags: 8, entities, database

I want to get a list that the items with a specific term in the top (like promote). The query would be like:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('type', 'news')
  ->sort('field_product_category', $tid, '<>') //Error <>
  ->range(0, 5);
```

Can I put calculation in sort condition? I do not want to make 2 queries.

Comment: Do you only care about having the items with a specific term at the top and then you don't care about the sorting of the rest? Because if that's the case I would just load all the nodes into an array and sort the array by that key after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can sort that way with an entity query.  But with a select query, you have more flexibility.

I would try something like this:

```
$database = \Drupal::service('database');

$query = $database->select('node_field_data', 'nfd')
  ->fields('nfd', ['id']);


$query->condition('nfd.status', 1);
$query->condition('nfd.type', 'news');
$query->range(0, 5);

$query->leftJoin('field_product_category', 'pc', 'pc.entity_id = nfd.nid');
$query->addExpression('pc.field_product_category_target_id <> :target_tid', 'is_featured', [':target_tid', $target_tid]);

$query->orderBy('is_featured');
$query->orderBy('nfd.changed');

$matches = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```